# Help to understand the validity of an adulterated non-linear Einstein-Hilbert action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, curvature, variational-calculus

I am interested in a gravitational actions of this form:

$$
S=\iiiint d^4x\sqrt[4]{\left( R\sqrt{|\det g|} + L_m\sqrt{|\det g|} \right)^2 +L_a} 
$$

where $L_m$ is a matter Lagrangian and $L_a$ is an additional contribution.

So far, I have derived the equations of motions as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\delta S&=\iiiint \delta \sqrt[4]{\left( R\sqrt{|\det g|} + L_m\sqrt{|\det g|} \right)^2 +L_a} d^4x \\
&=\iiiint \frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{\left( R\sqrt{|\det g|} + L_m\sqrt{|\det g|} \right)^2+L_a}}\left[\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu v}}((  R\sqrt{|\det g|} + L_m\sqrt{|\det g|}   )^2 + L_a) \right] \delta g^{\mu\nu}  d^4x\\
&=\iiiint \frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{\left( R\sqrt{|\det g|} + L_m\sqrt{|\det g|} \right)^2+L_a}}\left[\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu v}}(  R\sqrt{|\det g|} + L_m\sqrt{|\det g|}   )^2 + \frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu v}}L_a \right] \delta g^{\mu\nu}  d^4x
\end{align}
$$

Then with the usual eliminations, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
0&= \frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu v}}(  R\sqrt{|\det g|} + L_m\sqrt{|\det g|}   )^2 + \frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu v}}L_a\\
\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu v}}  R\sqrt{|\det g|}&=-  \frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu v}} L_m\sqrt{|\det g|}   - \underbrace{ (2(  R\sqrt{|\det g|} + L_m\sqrt{|\det g|}   ) )^{-1} \frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu v}}L_a}_{\text{new term}}
\end{align}
$$

---

With simplifications $L_m\to 0$ and, taking a specific case of inteterest $L_a\to \mathbf{v}^T g^{\mu\nu}\mathbf{v}$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is a 4-vector;

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu v}}  R\sqrt{|\det g|}&=  - (2 R\sqrt{|\det g|} )^{-1} \frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu v}}(\mathbf{v}^Tg^{\mu\nu}\mathbf{v})\\
&=  - (2 R\sqrt{|\det g|} )^{-1} \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T
\end{align}
$$

Other than showing that $- (2 R\sqrt{|\det g|} )^{-1} \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T$ is symmetric (which I have), what else can be done to gain confidence, that my procedure produces acceptable physical solutions?

Does the presence of the term $- (2 R\sqrt{|\det g|} )^{-1}$ undermine me in some way?

Comment: Note on notation: $\mathbf{v}^T g^{\mu\nu}\mathbf{v}$ mixes index-free ($\mathbf{v}$) and indicial ($g^{\mu\nu}$) objects. Better pick only one type of notation (and since your variations already use indices, better stick with that).

Comment: @A.V.S. So... I should write $\mathbf{v}^T g^{\mu\nu} \mathbf{v}$ as $X^\mu X^\nu g_{\mu\nu}$?